# Count + / - for checkbox click and unclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When a user clicks the checkbox the counter #counter +1, thats fine,  but when he unchecks it does not -1 for the same checkbox. I want to +1 when they click a particular checkbox and when unchecking -1.

--JS--

```
$('.CheckBox').toggle(function(){
    $('#Counter').html('( '+i+' Selected )');
    i++;
}, function() {

    $('#Counter').html('( '+i+' Selected )');
    i--;
});
```

---PHP---

```
do { ?>

<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:20px; background-color:#FF5300;" class="CheckBox" id="<?php echo $row_EX['x1']; ?>">

<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row_EX['x2']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row_EX['x3']; ?>" style="cursor:pointer; ">

<span style="position:relative; top:-2px; font-family:arial; color:#000; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $row_EX['lx4']; ?></span>

</div>

<div style="height:1px; width:1px;"></div>
<?php } while ($row_EX = mysql_fetch_assoc($EY)); ?>    

<span style="position:relative; left:10px; top:6px; font-family:arial; font-size:16px;" id="counter">(0 Selected)</span>
```

Comment: It's better to first change `i` value and then update html for `#Counter`. Actually, there's a possibility, your code is working, but you was mislead by bad program logic.

Comment: 1.) What an ugly code!
2.) That is not your HTML, but PHP!
3.) Where is `i` initialized?

Comment: @Amberlamps Why do you say that?
What is so ugly and what part is so ugly?

Comment: @Amberlamps  Where "I" is initialized is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.CheckBox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i--;
  }
  $('#Counter').html('( '+i+' Selected )');
});
```

Make sure you initialise `var i = 0;` when the page loads.

Comment: It is initialized, but was not given in the question.

Comment: I'd even write `$('#Counter').html('( '+(i += 2*this.checked - 1;)+' Selected )');` ;-)

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov It is arguably a silly approach, but it does have the edge *if* there are a very large number of `.CheckBox` elements on the DOM (see my comment on @phirschybar's answer). Although your point is valid and it is probably better to count the number of checked elements on the fly, exactly as phirschybar's answer does.

Answer (score 3):

try a different approach:

```
$('.CheckBox').change(function(){

  var n_checkboxes_checked = $('.CheckBox:checked').length;
  $('#Counter').html(n_checkboxes_checked + ' Selected');
});
```

Comment: I wanted to propose similar solution, but I will upvote yours instead.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, counting the actual number of checked checkboxes on the fly. +1 (caveat: with a very large number of `.CheckBox` elements on the DOM, this may take a long time and be quite memory intensive)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code that deals with clicking on checkbox here. `.toggle` in jquery just deals with hiding/showing element.

upd. i think you don't need to go through all `.checkbox` elements as others have proposed.. and you don't need global variable `i`. Instead something like

```
$('.CheckBox input').click(function(){
    $('#Counter').html('( '+$('.CheckBox input:checked').length()+' Selected )');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the jQuery documentation it says....

```
    Description: Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks.

.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [, handler(eventObject)] )
handler(eventObject)A function to execute every even time the element is clicked.
handler(eventObject)A function to execute every odd time the element is clicked.
```

so it has nothing to do with check/uncheck

do it this way

```
$('.CheckBox').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        $('#Counter').html('( '+i+' Selected )');
        i++;
    }else{
        $('#Counter').html('( '+i+' Selected )');
        i--;    
    }
}
```

yes click instead of toggle...i missed that and u shud use attr instead

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ENxnK/2

Use change(), not toggle()

```
var i = 0;
$('.CheckBox').change(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('checked') ) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i--;
    }

    $('#Counter').html('( ' + i + ' Selected )');
});
```

​

Comment: It does on Chrome, but it may be safer to user change() instead of click(). Edited, thanks.

Comment: @waitinforatrain FYI it is always safer to use `.change` for checkboxes - IE<7 (and possibly others) fire `.click` before the value of `this.checked` has been changed.

Comment: Actually w/o jQuery it was better to use `onclick` on checkboxes due to older IE versions, but jQuery normalize events and `change` will be better.