# Click and unclick checkbox with count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to let the user check a max of 4 checkboxes which I can achieve in the below code.    When the user unchecks then the count must go one down and they must be permitted to check an alternative one.

How can I let the user uncheck a checkbox and the count reduces by the click they perform and let them check the max required checkbox only.

*note: If the user has checked a max of 4 checkboxes then when they click the 5th one a message is shown and that particular 5th boxes is unchecked, which I have already done.

```
$('.chkbx').click(function() {


if (kgcount>="5") {
    alert("You have selected 4 items");
    $(this).prop("checked", false);

    } 

});
```

Kindly let me know if I have missed anything.

PS: for some reason I checked this and it does not work for me - [Count + / - for checkbox click and unclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120838/count-for-checkbox-click-and-unclick)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699839/restricting-user-to-check-checkbox-in-jquery/18700148#18700148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to check number of checkboxes checked.

```
$('.chkbx').change(function() {
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length>=5){
        alert("You have selected 4 items");
        $(this).prop("checked",false);   
        return;
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JhUzP/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
var kgcount  = 1;
$('.chkbx').click(function() {


if (kgcount>="5") {
    alert("You have selected 4 items");
    $(this).prop("checked", false);

    } 
kgcount++;

});
```